# Panning and Zooming in Codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to implement the panning and zooming. I want to pan and zoom a component which has a object( an animal). I want to zoom and pan on this component. I got to know that I have to use pinch method but am unable to figure out how.

The code am using is,

```
public class sample extends Component
{

   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      super.paint(g);
      g.drawArc(100,100,50,50,0,180);
   }
   @Override
   protected boolean pinch(float scale)
   {
      return true;  
   }
}
```

I am including it in a form and I want to zoom and pan. Please Help!!!!

Comment: Added Java tag for syntax highlighting

Answer (score 0):

Check out this block from the `ImageViewer` class [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/components/ImageViewer.java#L405-L421).

```
protected boolean pinch(float scale) {
    zoom = currentZoom * scale;
    if(zoom < MIN_ZOOM) {
        zoom = MIN_ZOOM;
    } else {
        if(zoom > MAX_ZOOM) {
            zoom = MAX_ZOOM;
        }            
    }
    updatePositions();
    repaint();
    return true;
}
```

Pinch is called when there is a user gesture. It doesn't imply repaint so you need to invoke that. If you return false for pinch the event will propagate down the hierarchy.

You should check out that class for panning as well as it implements all of that.

Notice that you should make the component focusable otherwise it won't get event notification.